# How to remove flex-items inheriting parent height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout:

```css
.content-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.view-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.zavod,
.ekipa {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="view-content">
    <section class="zavod">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
    <section class="ekipa">
      <p>Some more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
    </section>
  </div>  
</div>
```

What I would like to accomplish is for `.zavod` and `.ekipa` to have different heights. Now this works inside a single flex container, but when I nest multiple ones it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `align-items` property to `flex-start` on your `.view-content` container. `align-items` defaults to `stretch` which is why both `.zavod` and `.ekipa`, as flex children are "stretched" to match the height of each other:

```css
.content-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.view-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.zavod,
.ekipa {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="view-content">
    <section class="zavod">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
    <section class="ekipa">
      <p>Some more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
    </section>
  </div>  
</div>
```

[Here's a lovely guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on how to flexbox which I refer to from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question code will be like this. Just add `.content-container{flex-direction: column;}`, `.view-content{align-items: flex-start;flex-direction: row;}`. That is it. You need read [csstricks flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.content-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.view-content {
  align-items: flex-start; /* If you want to set two column top align */
  /* align-items: center; If you want to set tow column vertically center */
  /* align-items: flex-end; If you want to set column align on bottom center */
  /* align-items: stretch; If you want to set two column same height */
  /* align-items: baseline; If you want to set two column align by text align */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.zavod,
.ekipa {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="view-content">
    <section class="zavod">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
    <section class="ekipa">
      <p>Some more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
    </section>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For infos and in some cases, you can also reset the margin on the side(s) you want it to stand away from

```css
.content-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background:gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.view-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.zavod,
.ekipa {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
section {
  margin :auto 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="view-content">
    <section class="zavod">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
    <section class="ekipa">
      <p>Some more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
    </section>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items: center;` to the container

```css
.content-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.view-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.zavod,
.ekipa {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="view-content">
    <section class="zavod">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
    <section class="ekipa">
      <p>Some more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
      <p>Even more text</p>
    </section>
  </div>  
</div>
```